# how to avoid possible multiple enumeration warning

Tags: c#

For below piece of code I am getting warning `possible multiple enumeration` as for `Count` I am doing `g.ToList()` and for `Students` I am doing `g.Select`, two time enumeration for group items.

How to avoid it?

```
 var redefineSchoolDatas = group.Select(g => new RedefineSchoolData
        {
            ClassName = g.Key,
            Count = g.ToList().Count,
            Students = g.Select(s => new Student
            {
                StudentName = s.StudentName,
                StudentAge = s.StudentAge
            }).ToList(),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: add what group is, isnt `Count = g.ToList().Count,` the same as  `Count = g.Count()`, is the tolist on Students  needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to avoid enumerating the `IEnumerable` twice:

```
var redefineSchoolDatas = group.Select(g =>
{
    var elementsInGroup = g.ToList();
    return new RedefineSchoolData
    {
        ClassName = g.Key,
        Count = elementsInGroup.Count,
        Students = elementsInGroup.Select(s => new Student
        {
            StudentName = s.StudentName,
            StudentAge = s.StudentAge
        }).ToList(),
    }
}).ToList();
```

However, I would suggest you refrain from having a `Count` property in your `RedefineSchoolData` class. Maintaining a `Count` separate from the collection (`Students`) is not a good idea: imagine you delete a student - then you also need to remember to update the `Count`. Instead, you could build your class like so:

```
class RedefineSchoolData
{
    public Student Students { get; set; }
    public int Count => Students.Count;
    // Other properties kept out for brevity
}

// Now your LINQ statements could be:
var redefineSchoolDatas = group.Select(g =>
    new RedefineSchoolData
    {
        ClassName = g.Key,
        Students = g.Select(s => new Student
        {
            StudentName = s.StudentName,
            StudentAge = s.StudentAge
        }).ToList(),
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks and appreciated for your answer and explanation.